# How can I obtain the installation directory (absolute path) of an OSGi bundle by its name?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, equinox

Is it possible to get the installation directory in kind of an absolute path of a specific OSGi bundle by its name during runtime? If yes, how?

E. g. I am having a bundle with a symbolic name of `com.example.e4.rcp.todo.service`. From a class in a different bundle but in the same application, I want to determine the absolute installation path of `com.example.e4.rcp.todo.service` during runtime.

I don't know whether this is relevant, but I am using Eclipse Equinox.

Comment: what is for you the "installation directory of a bundle" ?

Comment: Is this really just OSGi or is it an Eclipse RCP or plugin? Eclipse has methods for finding objects in other bundles.

Comment: Can you explain wat you mean with this as well as what you want to do with it? In OSGi, there is no installation directory. At most there is a directory per bundle for that bundle's scratch pad. Which you can get with `bundle.getBundleContext().getDataFile(path)`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reliable way to get this information because OSGi bundles do not need to have an "installation directory".

For example, if I install a bundle in the following way, there will be nothing associated with the bundle that has any connection to the filesystem:

```java
context.installBundle("urn:mybundle", new URL("http://...").openStream());
```

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse Equinox has the FileLocator helper class available for resolving resources within Equinox.

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/FileLocator.html

Specifically, FileLocator#resolve might help you out. However:

> Note however that users of this API should not assume too much about the results of this method. While it may consistently return a file: URL in certain installation configurations, others may result in jar: or http: URLs.

I'd be cautious relying too much on it if you won't have full control of the configuration.

Comment: This will grab a lot of dependencies just to locate a File relative to a "bundle" :\\\

Answer (score 2):

In Equinox OSGi you can use [FileLocator.getBundleFile(...)](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/FileLocator.html#getBundleFile-org.osgi.framework.Bundle-)

```
File bundleFile = FileLocator.getBundleFile(bundle).getCanonicalFile();
```

It returns the File object of the Bundle Jar file or the Bundle directory depending on how the bundle is installed (packed or unpacked like in a Eclipse plugin).

I have added the `getCanonicalFile()` at the end because I have encountered often relative path elements like `/workspace/project_xyz/bin/../`.

Comment: This will grab a lot of dependencies just to locate a File relative to a "bundle" :\\\

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store some data owned by the bundle, you shall use [BundleContext.getDataFile(String)](https://www.cct.lsu.edu/~rguidry/ecl31docs/api/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getDataFile(java.lang.String))